# How to visualize GeoJson on new Angular GMaps component?

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-components

I am building an Angular Web Application using the Angular GMaps component:

```
<div id="map-container">
    <google-map (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)">
      <map-marker [position]="markerPosition" [options]="markerOptions"></map-marker>
    </google-map>
</div>
```

Now I want to visualize multiple geoJson strings on that map.
I have seen different implementations where they have a <data-layer [geoJson]=...> component. 
Is there anything similiar in the GMaps component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map!: GoogleMap
```

did the trick!

```
this.map.data.loadGeoJson(geoJson);
```

now loads GeoJson on the map properly.